# Split not-atomar value into multiple rows with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have some not atomar data in a database like this:

| ID | Component ID List |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123, 456 |
| 2 | 123, 345 |

I need to transform those table into a view that provides the "Component ID List" in a way, that I can use joins. Expected result:

| ID | Component ID List |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | 345 |

Because I have this case in quite a few tables I look for the possibility to create a reusable way to perform this action, e.g. with a SQL-function. The tables have different column-names so the function would need a parameter, like this:

```
SELECT *, split_values("Component ID List") FROM xyz
```

I know the best way would be to fix the problem in the raw-data but that's not possible in this case.

Any suggestions how to solve this the best way possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest(string_to_array(Component_ID_List, ', '))`:

```
SELECT ID,
unnest(string_to_array(Component_ID_List, ', ')) as Component_ID_List 
FROM table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eb911009c725aa80bd35bcc98102e514)

Comment: Thank you. The fact that really interests me is, how could I implement a function as unnest in SQL by myself? The fact is didn't described in the original post is that the structure of the list can differ (some IDs, some text, ...) and some more logic would be required on top.